# Invalid repository name while pulling an image in docker

Tags: docker, dockerhub

The repository owner on github shared the following repository `(mxtsit/myswitchXSS)` with me and it's not showing up on the docker hub unlike couple of previous repositories he had shared.

I am getting the following error, despite having correct repository name:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker pull mxtsit/myswitchXSS
2014/11/12 17:53:43 Invalid repository name (myswitchXSS), only [a-z0-9-_.] are allowed
```

I suspect that docker doesn't recognize any Uppercase letters as mentioned in the error
description `only [a-z0-9-_.] are allowed` , please correct me if I am wrong. I am wondering if there is any official documentation available which talks about valid repository names on docker?

In the recent past, whatever repositories I have pulled were in small case and has `.` notation. Is there any way I can overcome this problem? Also, I can't find the repository on Dockerhub unlike previous repositories which ideally should be there as I can see it on my github account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be right. I haven't seen a repository with upper case.

try this:

```
$ sudo docker pull https://<registry>/repositories/mxtsit/myswitchXSS
```

In this case, Docker bypasses the Docker Hub. However the security is not guaranteed  because there won't be any checksum checks.

Currently registry redirects to s3 urls for downloads, going forward all downloads need to be streamed through the registry. The Registry will then abstract the calls to S3 by a top-level class which implements sub-classes for S3 and local storage.

Token is only returned when the X-Docker-Token header is sent with request.

Basic Auth is required to pull private repos. Basic auth isn't required for pulling public repos, but if one is provided, it needs to be valid and for an active account.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. By using `https://<registry>/repositories/mxtsit/myswitchXSS` , did you mean to say that I should use `github.com` in place of `<registry>` or should I directly use the URL `https://github.com/mxtsit/myswitchXSS` which I used to access the repository on github? Please clarify. Because when I used ` sudo docker pull `https://github.com/mxtsit/myswitchXSS` , I get the following `2014/11/12 19:30:25 Invalid repository name (ex: "registry.domain.tld/myrepos")`

Comment: Maybe you need to be authenticated to pull, because this repository is not public.

Comment: The repository is not public. However, since the owner of the repository has shared the repository with me on github, don't you think that I already have authentication for the same? If there is another type of authentication you are talking about, please let me know.

Comment: The best solution would be to change the name of the repository to lower case.

Comment: Hmm, I am wondering why someone down-voted this answer? Is there something wrong?